# giving a polygon a cost value

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, field-calculator

I am working in ArcMap modelbuilder, doing a cost path anaylsis. In my analysis I am running a pipeline. it will cost 100 dollars to cross or parallel a road. I have buffered my roads in modelbuilder (which created about 14 polygon records in the buffered roads attribute table). I have added a new field to the attribute table called "cost" in modelbuilder. Now I want to make the value of all 14 records in the "cost" field equal 100 --- before I convert to raster. How do I make the value of all 14 records in the "cost" field 100?

Answer (score 1):

Use tool [Calculate Field](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/calculate-field.htm):

> Calculates the values of a field for a feature class, feature layer,
>   or raster.

[image]

Same thing without ModelBuilder:

[image]